# issue on adding selectize.js dropdown in cell in ag-Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to add selectize.js dropdown on the cell when editing the cell by clicking. The issue is selectize dropdown is not displaying. The expected behaviour of selectize should be like this selectize fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/key1rtw8/1/)

https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

plunker link:-
https://plnkr.co/edit/tA7vh3KXrGxkd3Fw

## index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
```

## .jsx

```
columnDefs = [
                  {
                    headerName: "Athlete",
                    field: "athlete",
                    editable:true,
                    cellEditor: "dropdownUI"
                  }
                ];
   
components = { dropdownUI: getdropdownUI() };
         
            function getdropdownUI() {
          function getdropdownUI() {}
          getdropdownUI.prototype.init = function(params) {
    this.eInput = document.createElement("input");
    this.eInput.value = params.value;
   
    // *************************************************************
   // adding selectize
   
     $(this.eInput).selectize({
      create: true,
      sortField: 'text',
      searchField: 'item',
      create: function (input) {
        return {
          value: input,
          text: input
        }
      }
    });
  };
          getdropdownUI.prototype.getGui = function() {
            return this.eInput;
          };
          getdropdownUI.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
            this.eInput.focus();
            this.eInput.select();
          };
          getdropdownUI.prototype.getValue = function() {
            return this.eInput.value;
          };
          getdropdownUI.prototype.destroy = function() {};
          getdropdownUI.prototype.isPopup = function() {
            return false;
          };
          return getdropdownUI;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## index.html

```
// selectize and jquery files
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
```

(1) Define it as `cellEditor`

```
  cellEditor: 'dynamicSelectizeEditor'
```

(2) Add it in `components`:-

```
 components: {
      dynamicEditor: getDynamicCellEditor()
    }
```

(3)  Define it as below:-

```
function getDynamicCellEditor() {
    function dynamicEditor() {  }
    dynamicEditor.prototype.init = function (params) {
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
        this.eGui.style =
            'height:100%;width:' + params.column.actualWidth + 'px';
        //Create and append select list
        this.selectEle = document.createElement('select');
        this.selectEle.style =
            'position:relative; height:100%;width:' +
            params.column.actualWidth +
            'px';
        this.selectEle.id = 'mySelect';
        this.selectEle.class = 'mySelect';

        this.selectEle = document.createElement('select');
        this.eGui.appendChild(this.selectEle);

        $(this.selectEle).selectize({   //<--- add selectize
            sortField: 'text',
            searchField: 'item',
            create: function (input) {
                selcts(input);
                return {
                    value: input,
                    text: input,
                };
            },
        });
        if (params.value !== '') {
            selcts(params.value);
        }
        function selcts(input) {
            $('.mySelect').each(function () {
                var selectize = $(this).selectize;
                selectize.addOption({
                    value: input,
                    text: input,
                }); //add option to it
            });
        }
    };
    dynamicEditor.prototype.getGui = function () {
        return this.eGui;
    };
    dynamicEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function () {
        this.eGui.focus();
        // this.eGui.select();
    };
    dynamicEditor.prototype.getValue = function () {
        return this.selectEle.value;
    };
    dynamicEditor.prototype.destroy = function () {};
    dynamicEditor.prototype.isPopup = function () {
        return true;  //as popup 
    };
    return dynamicEditor;
};
```